# Thread safe static collection, is this code safe

Tags: c#, thread-safety, cache

A small caching utility, can you tell if it is thread safe?

```
public static class CacheService
{
    private readonly static object locker = new object();
    private static Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, object>> data = new Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, object>>();


    public static void Insert(string partition, string key, object value)
    {
        lock (locker)
        {
            if (!data.ContainsKey(partition))
            {
                var newVal = new Dictionary<string, object>();
                newVal.Add(key, value);
                data.Add(partition, newVal);
            }
            else
            {
                if (!data[partition].ContainsKey(key))
                {
                    data[partition].Add(key, value);
                }
                else
                {
                    data[partition][key] = value;
                }
            }
        }
    }


    public static bool KeyExists(string partition, string key)
    {
        return data[partition] != null && data[partition][key] != null;
    }

    public static V Get<V>(string partition, string key)
    {
        return (V)data[partition][key];
    }

}
```

Comment: Why not just use a ConcurrentDictionary https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd287191(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 5):

No, it's not safe because you're locking only when writing. You prevent multiple writings to occur simultaneously but:

- Caller might call `KeyExists()` in the middle of `Insert()`, in this case:

  - `data[partition][key]` might be not `null` but still empty.
  - `data` or `data[partition]` might be in an intermediate invalid internal state.
- If you add a `Delete()` function then reading may go through the same indeterminate states.
- When calling `Get()` you can go through the same indeterminate states as above, plus if you add `Delete()` then you might be in the middle of that (also `Delete()` might be called after `KeyExists()` and before `Get()`).

---

That said let's see few other improvments you can make:

Calling `ContainsKey()` and then searching the value in the dictionary is pretty inefficient because search is done twice. There is a `TryGetValue()` method for this:

When you  have an `else` section you may want to keep the `if` condition *positive*, negation is a small `!` symbol which may be unnoticed.

with `dictionary[key] = value` you do not need to call `ContainsKey()`, that check is already done efficiently inside the setter.

In code (C#7, if earlier version you can't use `out var` and `sub` has to be declared before):

```
public static void Insert(string partition, string key, object value)
{
    lock (locker)
    {
        if (data.TryGetValue(partition, out var sub))
        {
            sub[key] = value;
        }
        else
        {
            sub = new Dictionary<string, object>();
            sub.Add(key, value);
            data.Add(partition, sub);
        }
    }
}
```

Now add locking also in the functions to read from the dictionary and you're almost done.

---

You do not validate parameters. I don't know if for your usage scenarios a null value (or an empty string) for `partition`, `key` and `values` are allowed or not. If not then you must validate your inputs. Something as simple as:

```
if (partition == null)
    throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(partition));

if (partition.Length == 0)
    throw new ArgumentException("Partition cannot be an empty string", nameof(partition));
```

What about a string made of spaces? In that case you might change second check to:

```
if (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(partition))
    throw new ArgumentException("Partition cannot be...", nameof(partition));
```

---

Now you can consider if `Monitor` (what's used by `lock`) is the most **appropriate synchronization mechanism** for your cache. If you expect multiple concurrent reads and (after an initial period) very few writes then a `ReadWriterLockSlim` may give you much much better performance. Profile.

---

I left these points to the end but they're actually the first things you should consider.

What about testing? Static methods are a nightmare for testing (if you want to replace them with something else at calling point). You **may** use a default singleton instance (not the perfect thing to do but better than nothing).

Your class has nothing of a cache. It's a sort of `MultiMap` but it has nothing to do with a cache. What I'd do? Design a not thread-safe `MultiMultiMap<TKeyOuter, TKeyInner, TValue>` (eventually considering to implement `ILookup`) which I might reuse somewhere else (even if the *standard* `MultiMap<TKey, TValue>` is probably much more common).

Now I can design a thread-safe access class around it (call it *cache* if you want).

Now you should start putting some caching logic inside this class, in this moment you have everything at calling point (because `CacheService` has too few responsibilities). What about:

- A method which accepts a `Func<object>` instead of object itself?
- A method to clear the cache.
- A method to set an expiration for each item.
- A method to limit the memory size used for caching.

Then you might want to abstract cache storage (memory in this case) from cache interface. What if objects you're constructing are pretty huge and expensive to build? Maybe switching to disk storage is still better than re-build them (for example if they come from network data...). Move interface to a base class (or...an interface) and derive this memory cache from that.

---

Did you consider to use [System.Runtime.Caching.MemoryCache](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.caching.memorycache(v=vs.110).aspx) instead?

Comment: If the OP's going to `lock` every access, the collection becomes essentially single-threaded and will bottleneck performance in some cases. Kudos to you for suggesting alternative practices, but a bit of example code would go a long way. Still, +1.

Comment: It might not be, I think much depends on his access pattern. Monitor is a very lightweight synchronization primitive and it performs spin wait, great thing if protected code is very short. Profiling is best thing, IMO.

Comment: I don't think you got what I meant. I meant that if every access is synchronized, then there can be no concurrent accesses - implying that the collection can only be accessed by one thread at a time - thus having a possibility of making accesses to this collection a bottleneck in highly concurrent applications. Yes, `Monitor` based implementations have the lowest overhead among many synchronization primitives - but that wasn't the source of the bottleneck I was talking about - the source is the OP's thread-safety strategy. I'd prefer innately immutable collections with shared memory any day.

Comment: Concrete example: `Copy-On-Write` List pattern, just with contiguous unaltered sections being backed by the same memory between updated versions. Functional languages like Haskell and Erlang have this inbuilt, and I think Chris Okasaki's 'Purely Functional Data Structures' is a must-read on this subject.

Comment: Completely agree about that, a true concurrent lock free  "multi multimap" implementation would be a nice code to review (and to write). Anyway, what I mean is that most applications aren't so massively concurrent (and, more importantly, wrote to use immutable objects!) to require a "better" implementation than standard synchronization primitives. If, for example, this cache is used in an asp.net application with 100 (at worst) hits per minute MAYBE simple is better (of course if we're using C#!)

Comment: Keep in mind that I'm not into functional languages, thank you for the book reference, I really hope I can start to experiment in some real world applications with one of them (still not sure if I should go with haskell or f#...)

Comment: Try F#, it's more flexible with all the purity and you get all the .NET libraries at your disposal. About such a lock-free immutable Multimap, we have immutable lock-free maps already, it's probably just a matter of chaining them together (as you suggested yourself).And of note is that I have a multithreaded C# application that needs a memoization cache for computed values, with lookups and writes of the order of a **billion** a second (it's numerical code in a very tight loop)! I discarded the `Dictionary` cache because profiling told me that it was faster to recompute them than look them up!

Comment: True but chaining together two lock-free collections doesn't make the result thread-safe in this case (for example using two ConcurrentDictionary), I still remember the huge effort to write a lock-free linked list (fortunately it was just for fun, not production). Bilion a second queries is a **huge** number, especially if you store a large number of items (last time I "hit the floor" with a dicionary I split data into multiple dictionaries and kept them in a self-organizing list, fortunately there was a search pattern to exploit) but in my case computation wasn't trivial and I had no choice

Comment: I'd love to use F# but I _worry_ I won't change my (procedural) programming style if I'm not forced to, well I guess I should post all my attempts here on Code Review!!! See you there... :)

Comment: I'll try my best to "show you the light" of the FP way, as it were :P. Oh, both the Maps I was talking about are immutable, thus the result of chaining them together is also immutable. Lookups are lock-free. Any mutations just create new maps, and then the runtime can use software transactional memory (read: atomic updates) to see to it that there is little or no thread contention. Now if your runtime has no atomically updated references you're quite out of luck (the JVM does, though, as my primary language Scala internally relies on it).

Comment: :) A world free of locks is programmers' Valhalla!